# SwiftUI NavigationBar empty space under the title

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, ios15, xcode13

I was working on Xcode 12 and upgraded to 13. Now I'm seeing a weird empty space under the navigation bar title text.
I have shared some screenshots.

[image: Empty Space]

Here is the another image that have the scrollview, and the navigation bar is overlapping it.

Here is the code.

```
struct ProductDetailScreen: View {
        
    let product: Product
    
    @State var productVariation: ProductVariation?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.themeBackground
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{
                VStack{
                    AsyncImage(
                        url: URL(string: product.image)!,
                        placeholder: {
                            ProgressView()
                                .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color.themeBackground))
                        },
                        image: {
                            Image(uiImage: $0)
                                .resizable()
                        }
                    )
                    .frame(height: 250, alignment: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    FixedSpacer(height: 10)
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 60))]){
                        ForEach(product.variations, id: \.self) { variation in
                            VariationSizeButtonView(productVariation: $productVariation, variation: variation)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    if productVariation != nil {
                        NavigationButton(text: "Select Photos", destination: AnyView(SelectPhotosScreen(product: product, productVariation: self.productVariation!)))
                    }
                    
                }
                .frame(
                    minWidth: 0,
                    maxWidth: .infinity,
                    minHeight: 0,
                    maxHeight: .infinity,
                    alignment: .topLeading
                )
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 24)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(product.name)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

[image: Overlapping Scrollview]

Here is the code for select photo screen.

```
struct SelectPhotosScreen: View {
    
    @State private var id = 1
    @State var product: Product
    @State var uploadingPhotos = false
    @State var productVariation: ProductVariation
    @StateObject var selectedImagesViewModel = SelectedImagesViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var cartViewModel: CartViewModel
    
    let imageUploaderService = ImageUploaderService()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.themeBackground
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{
                VStack {
                    PhotoSelectionOptions(selectedImagesViewModel: selectedImagesViewModel)
                    SelectedPhotoDisplayer(selectedImagesViewModel: selectedImagesViewModel)
                }
                Spacer()
                if uploadingPhotos && (selectedImagesViewModel.pendingImages() > 0) {
                    ProgressView("Uploading....", value:  Float(selectedImagesViewModel.uploadedImages()), total: Float(selectedImagesViewModel.images.count))
                        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                if !selectedImagesViewModel.images.isEmpty && !uploadingPhotos{
                    RoundedButton(text: "Upload Photos", action: {
                        uploadingPhotos = true
                        imageUploaderService.uploadImages(selectedImagesViewModel: selectedImagesViewModel)
                    })
                }
                if (selectedImagesViewModel.pendingImages() <= 0) && (selectedImagesViewModel.uploadedImages() >= 1) {
                    NavigationButton(text: "Order Summary", destination: AnyView(OrderSummaryScreen(
                                                                                    cartItem: CartItem(
                                                                                        id: self.product.id,
                                                                                        selectedImages: self.selectedImagesViewModel,
                                                                                        product: self.product,
                                                                                        productVariation: self.productVariation
                                                                                    )
                                                                                )))
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 24)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Select Photos", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Both Screens are navigating from the home screen that's code is here.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let greet = Greeting().greeting()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            HomeScreen()
                .navigationTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
        .navigationAppearance(backgroundColor: .themeBackground, foregroundColor: .white)
    }
}
```

It only happened after upgrading Xcode to 13 and iOS 15.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share any relevant code as an [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: @koen I have added the code.

Comment: Can you pare it down to a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx I tried but unable to reduce the code, but i found one thing if I add the .navigationDisplayMode(.inline) on the navigation link instead of the destination screen code. It is working fine. So should I add it in the NavigationLink? so next activity have the inline navigation text?

Comment: Also have a look at the release notes of iOS 15 and see what changed.

Comment: @koen can you tell me what is good way to have the navigation title inline? Adding the modifier on the navigation link button? or in the Screen root view?

Answer (score 3):

Just set `.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)`